# How to change launcher icon

Tags: 10.04, launcher

Is there a way to customize a Lucid Lynx Launcher icon for various programs? There does not seem to be a way to do this using `Create Launcher` or Launcher properties. The application is not actually "installed" on the PC, the executable has just been copied. All I've been able to do so far is to add the command `/home/t32/bin/pc_linux/t32marm -c /home/t32/config_usb.t32` to a generic Launcher icon using `Create Launcher`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Launcher icons are stored in `/usr/share/applications`. Go to your terminal and type: `sudo nautilus /usr/share/applications`, then right click the application you want, select Properties and click the icon on the properties window. Now you can set it to any icon you want.

*edits
*here is an example .desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]   
Name=Give me a name!    
Comment=Explain me here!    
Icon=/home/t32/t32.png   
Exec=/home/t32/bin/pc_linux/t32marm -c /home/t32/config_usb.t32   
Terminal=false   
Type=Application   
Categories=This is important, select a category that is present  
StartupNotify=true
```

*use one of the following as category: `Accessibility, Customization, Education, Games, 
Internet, Office, System, Accessories, Developer, Graphics, Media, Other`. **Exec** is the command to run, **Icon** is an **absolute path** to where the icon lives. Usually you wouldn't need to alter anything else. You may keep this as a scratch and reuse.

*copy this to a `whatever-you-name.desktop` file, edit as needed and put the file in the `/usr/share/applications` directory. If paths are true, it will pop up in the gnome menu. I don't know if lucid had `Unity` or `gnome3`, but if it has, when you search it by the name you gave it, it will be visible in the `unity lens`, `gnome activities` thing. If you have `gnome2`, it would be grouped under the corresponding category in the applications menu.

*And this kind of launcher are so cute that they are valid in GNOME, KDE and (probably) all others.

Comment: The application is not actually "installed" on the PC, the executable has just been copied. All I've been able to do so far is to add the command `/home/t32/bin/pc_linux/t32marm -c /home/t32/config_usb.t32` using `Create Launcher`.

Comment: if the launcher icon is on the launcher, it should be created via drag and drop or a `something.desktop` file should be living in one of `/usr/share/applications` or `~/<.gnome or .gnome2>/apps` directory. A .desktop file is a plain text file. I you want, I will post an example .desktop file, and if you tell the icon path, i can post the text for you to copy and paste and create a custom one.

Comment: That would be terrific. I can put the icon anywhere, eg: `/home/t32/t32.png`.

Comment: I've edited this post to contain the answer, the .desktop file contents.

Comment: @jacknad You're welcome :)

Answer (score 12):

Launcher shortcuts are *.desktop text files. They can be in:

- $HOME/.local/share/applications
- /usr/local/share/applications
- /usr/share/applications

Look in the latter directory for examples.

The .desktop files have a line defining the icon: `Icon=icon_file_base_name`. You can set a full path to your icon file, or use only the basename without extension, if you put the icon file into the right place.

That place can be under `$HOME/.icons/` or `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons`. They should be .svg or .png files. If .png, there should be at least a 48x48 pixels version, though there may be other sizes.

For a simple example, try to put a 48x48 .png file called example.png into `/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/` and also do

```
cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/index.theme /usr/local/share/icons/hicolor/
```

This way, you don't need the full path in the .desktop file. Just `Icon=example`. And it is available to all users on the machine.

See the [specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) for all the details.