# How do I change the unity launcher dash home icon in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, unity-dash

Okey, Before anyone rates this as duplicate of anything! I have researched. And I am sorry if my response for my previous questions was bad, I did not mean to do so, some personal things happened, I'm sorry. Okey, I was looking for ways to make ubuntu look like mac and i have done this before. I used [this](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html) link to change the unity launcher dash icon to the apple icon. I know that this is for ubuntu 14.04 and I have 12.04 but I've done this before! I changed the icon to the apple logo and back the the beloved ubuntu logo. but for some reason this is not doing it again! whenever I enter:

> sudo mv launcher_bfb.png /usr/share/unity/icons/

I get :

> mv: cannot stat `launcher_bfb.png': No such file or directory

how do I fix this? thank you guys soo much for responding even though I have not responded properly in the past :)

Comment: I am not sure what you did in the past, but far more easy than actually replace the icon (I assume that is what you are trying to do) is editing the "Icon=" line of its desktop file. (We are talking about the "Files" icon, right?)

Comment: And where is that file?

Comment: It is in `/usr/share/applications`, but a cleaner procedure is to leave that file alone, but copy it to `~/.local/share/applications` (`cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`) , then edit it as described here: http://askubuntu.com/a/190171/72216 After logout / in, you will see the changed icon.

Comment: I cant seem to find it there. All i see are files which launch applications

Comment: Those are the ones that appear in Dash and the launcher (try and drag one over the launcher).

Comment: I want to change the icon of the dash itself. Not any other icon. I have an apple icon there and I want back the ubuntu 12.04 icon

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your command is that there is no launcher_bfb.png file in your ~home directory.

Also I wouldn't follow a guide to tweak a newer release of ubuntu to tweak an old one.

Comment: okey, I have made sure that I have the file and now when I try to move i get : mv: cannot move `launcher_bfb.png' to `/usr/share/unity/icons/': Not a directory