# How to change the Launcher icon of a Chrome app

Tags: launcher, google-chrome, chromium, chrome-extension

A installed a Chrome app, ran it and locked it to the Launcher to run it easily in the future.

PROBLEM: I don't like its icon.

QUESTION: How to change the icon of a Chrome app?

*See also: [How to change launcher icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190170/how-to-change-launcher-icon)*

Answer (score 2):

First, get the identifier of the extension, by searching it on Chrome store and extracting it from the URL. For instance, LINE is at `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/line/menkifleemblimdogmoihpfopnplikde?hl=en` so the identifier is `menkifleemblimdogmoihpfopnplikde`.

Now in your home directory open the file `~/.local/share/applications/chrome-menkifleemblimdogmoihpfopnplikde-Default.desktop` (replace with the correct identifier)

At the `Icon=` line, replace the value with the path of a 48x48 PNG file of your choice.

The problem with this approach is that for some reason the icon is reset at every reboot, so you have to do it every time, or set some script to do it.