# Change Files folder icon to Ubuntu logo icon?

Tags: icons, directory, dock

what's the best way to just change the Files folder icon to Ubuntu logo icon ?

like this icon that I have ?[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change launcher icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190170/how-to-change-launcher-icon) Try this duplicate and if it doesn't work for you update your question stating why and I will retract the duplicate nomiation. Thank you.

Comment: Like https://askubuntu.com/questions/79110/how-can-i-assign-custom-icons-to-folders ?

Comment: the Files folder is not in that folder. Does it has a different name ?

Comment: `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIDHc.png